# Grails/aNimble on Windows : Getting cannot find the specified path

Tags: grails

I am trying to setup [aNimble](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimble/) on Windows following [this](https://known.phyks.me/2015/installing-animble-on-windows) article.

I have setup the Java and MySQL (xampp) on Windows and both are working properly.

Now, as the final step I need to execute

```
grails prod execute-database-scripts-all
```

but I am getting `cannot find the specified path`. Even when I type `grails` only I get the same error. I have zero experience in Grails, but it seems that I need to install Grails first on the PC. Until I do this, I want to know is there anything else that I need to do this to successfully execute this command.

What are the three portions of this command `grails`, `prod` and `execute-database-scripts-all`

Comment: The most recent release of aNimble is from the end of 2012. You're probably going to have to do a lot more work than it's worth to use this.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that Windows is unable to find grails executable anywhere it looks (in any paths specified in PATH system property) when you typing `grails` command. You may have to follow [this guide](http://www.grailsexample.net/installing-a-grails-development-environment-on-windows/) in order to install grails application framework properly in your system (also, make sure you are installing a correct version of grails compatible with your distribution of aNimble) and then retry.

Grails is a web application framework and which provides a set of tools to develop, build and run web applications like aNimble, `prod` is a command line option for grails telling it to run in a production mode and `execute-database-scripts-all` is aNimble-specific command to initialize it's database.